# Calling dispatch_async in a for loop

Tags: ios, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to call a dispatch_async queue inside a for-loop. A new queue is added for every loop.

```
queue1 = dispatch_queue_create("com..queue1", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

for(NSDictionary *dictInfo in dataArray) {
      dispatch_async(queue1,^(void) {

          NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
          HeaderValueGenerator *valueGenerator = [HeaderValueGenerator instance] ;
          valueGenerator.apiPath = @"path";
          valueGenerator.request = request;
          [request addValue:[valueGenerator createSignature] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Authorization-Client"];
          //request is used to call the server. (asynchronous call and hence inside dispatch_async)
     }
}
```

The request is used to make asynchronous call to the server. The server responds with mismatched signature. The createSignature method is not run for some of the requests.

The following is a thread safe singleton. I'm using the singleton as a shared resource for various NSURLRequest for different API calls. So I can't be defining it in all the request objects rather call them using this singleton.

HeaderValueGenerator.h

```
 #import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>
 @interface HeaderValueGenerator : NSObject
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *apiPath;
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableURLRequest *request;
 + (HeaderValueGenerator *)instance;
 - (NSString *)createSignature;
 @end
```

HeaderValueGenerator.m

```
+ (HeaderValueGenerator *)sharedInstance {
    static HeaderValueGenerator *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });    
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (NSString *)createSignature {
    // String hashing and data encoding the header values for special header fields 

    return SignedString;
}
```

When this program runs through the for loop, a few of the loops doesn't  execute the createSignature method. As a result I get a bad response from the server. Is there a better way to use dispatch_async?
Is there a deadlock?

**EDIT**

```
-(void)createSignature{
    @synchronized(self) {
        // ... do stuff ...
    }
}
```

Will this help? Defining the method inside `synchronized(self)`?

Comment: Your `createSignature` method will be called once for each loop iteration. Why don't you think it does? Keep in mind that if `createSignature` is not thread safe, you will have problems.

Comment: Does that mean even if createSignature is a method inside the singletonclass (which is threadsafe), I would have this issue?

Comment: Due to using `dispatch_async`, there will likely be concurrent calls to `createSignature`. If that method isn't thread safe, you will have problems. It doesn't matter if `sharedInstance` is thread safe or not (of course it needs to be too - and it is).

Comment: Hi @rmaddy I have made some edit. can you verify?

Comment: There are important details omitted here: what exactly does `createSignature` do, how its results are stored/used, and how do you make sure that you use those results **after** they have been actually computed. Your loop simply queues bunch of blocks on a queue and you cannot assume that they're done running by the time your program hash finished running the `for` loop.

Comment: @Andrey I have made some more edits. Can you advice me on this?

Comment: What do you do after the for loop?  How do you know that "a few of the loops don't execute"?  Why do you think you need to do this header generation asynchronously and concurrently?  Have you tried just doing it in the for loop?  Is your hash function really that expensive?

Comment: @DesperateLearner Thanks for edits. Now it looks like the code inside `dispatch_async()` doesn't have any meaningful effect. You are creating `NSMutableURLRequest` **inside** the block, and once block completes, this request will be destroyed. You are not sending it anywhere.

Comment: This singleton class is used for 18 such request objects.